# Impact of iOS9 on a running development with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, ios8, ios9, phonegap-build

I'm working with external developers on a quite standard hybrid iOS app, which will be developed using PhoneGap.
The team just started about a week ago, and asks me if the code should be "upgraded/developed" for iOS9. This would require an extra 4 days work (on a 12 weeks project)..
The app does not use any built-in feature such as the camera and s.o.
The app just allows users to register and to view/browse content. That's quite all. Some data will be stored on the server, some data locally on the user's device..

I am not a developer, but I cannot see where the impact of iOS9 could be on a quite standard app development. True, the initial scope was iOS8, but we hardly started the development, and functionalities are very basic.. 
Can anyone share his view or experience on this?
Thanks !
Anna

Comment: you should ask them about which changes have to be done and why 4 days. We can't answer that without knowing anything about your app, what you told us isn't enough. If they compile the app with xcode 6 everything they did for ios 8 should work on ios 9 without changes

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, but I was just checking if anyone could share his/her experience on this... My contact argues they have set up some "basic libraries" and "started some DB setup"... I suspect this company wanting to abuse my limited knowledge of iOS development. I cannot believe a 1-2 day effort can result in a 3-4 day rework.. So if anyone has some experience in moving code from XCode6 to Xcode7, I would be pleased to hear your experiences...